# Calling customer service results in 401 Unauthorized

Tags: oauth-2.0, axapta, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

We are trying to connect to a custom Dynamics 365 Finance service operation but are struggling to authorize.

We've set up an app registration

- Redirect_uri set to the dynamics url (root)
- Enabled implicit grant (both for access tokens and ID tokens)
- Single tenant
- Assigned the "Dynamics ERP > CustomService.FullAccess" API permission
- Assigned the "Dynamics ERP > Odata.FullAccess" API permission
- Assigned "Dynamicd ERP > Connector.FullAccess" API permission + granted admin consent for entire AD
- Created a secret

We've added the Application (client ID) within the Dynamics 365 environment with a user which has System Administrator role
We can successfully retrieve access tokens both via Postman and .NET (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)
[image]
we tried to reach both https://xxxxxxdevaossoap.cloudax.dynamics.com &https://xxxxxxdevaos.cloudax.dynamics.com

Yet when we call custom services, we get a 401 UnAuthorized
[image]
A call to Odata also fails for the same reason.
[image]

Comment: [Troubleshoot service authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/troubleshoot-service-authentication) might contain some ideas.

Comment: Are you missing the `tenante_id`? I haven't had to do this in a couple years. Here's an article that might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test

I vaguely remember there being `GUID` that you might need that you get from your endpoint permissions, but that might be needed for logic apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify `resource` in your request for OAuth token (and verify token at https://jwt.io for `aud` (Audience) field).
It should be same as your primary url without `/` at the end (like `https://d365fo-10-12345678baef10230aos.cloudax.dynamics.com`).

Also verify that *Azure Active Directory applications* (`mi=SysAADClientTable`) **Client Id** is equal to `appid` field in the token (and without any special characters).

You can always inspect Windows Event Log `Microsoft-Dynamics-AX-WebApi/Operational`
There is good information like this:

```
Source:      Microsoft-Dynamics-AX-WebApi
Category:    WebApiOwinConfigurationMissingError
Level:       Error
Description: Web API Owin Authentication Configuration Missing Error
infoMessage: Can read the token but failed validating token with exception 
'IDX10214: Audience validation failed. 
Audiences: 'https://d365fo-10-12345678baef10230aos.cloudax.dynamics.com/'. 
Did not match:  validationParameters.
ValidAudience: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences:
 'https://d365fo-10-12345678baef10230aos.cloudax.dynamics.com,
 00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000,
 Microsoft.ERP''
```

Comment: Thanks for the event log location. We found our problem in there. Ended up being related to sending it to "devaossoap" instead of "devaos". Although we tested both before but I guess we must've changed something else somewhere in the mean time. Thanks, man!